# A test case needs 5 mins of wait. During these 5 mins I want to run other test cases

Tags: webdriver, selenium2, phpunit

A test case needs 5 mins of wait. During these 5 mins I want to run other test cases.
After 5 mins I want to check the necessary condition of 1st test case which is on hold for last 5 mins.

How to implement this scenario?

For ex:
Steps

1. Run 1st testcase.
2. In the middle of 1st test case it needs to wait for recurring payment for 5 mins.
3. During these 5 mins I want to run other testcases, like test2, test3, etc..
4. After 5 min I want to check whether the recurring payment was received or not in 1st testcase.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. To provide more details we need more details.

Comment: What kind of information you need? (I am using LAMP stack, phpunit, webdriver)

Comment: Flagged. Please provide more details.

Comment: I don't know - I don't use phpunit, I use Python. In Python, it would be possible to start another driver instance and run different set of tests routines, while waiting for the other one. No idea how to do it in PHP, but maybe someone else does. Showing some code might help. If not, try asking on stack overflow. with code.

Comment: @Ojha, I think you're asking the wrong question here. Instead of saying "is it possible" I would suggest gearing your question toward "how do I do it". Conceptually what you're looking to do seems possible, and truly an answer that really answered that would justify the answer somehow (probably by giving an example of how to do it). But it might not, and you wouldn't want to have an answer that satisfies your stated question but not your real question, would you? =)

Comment: @corsiKa, Thank you for teaching me the way to ask my query.

Comment: @OjhaRavi, **Show the code** for the "a test case needs 5 mins of wait" and the "other test cases".

Answer (score 1):

Split your long testcase into two -- one testcase does the stuff before the wait and returns a passing status if it was able to do start the process successfully.

The second half of your original testcase runs as a separate testcase that you run at the end of your suite

For example, if the test is "click the 'submit order' button and verify an email was sent", make that into two test cases: 1) click the submit button and verify the proper function was called, and 2) check the mail account to see if an order was received.